# Retrieving table value with php

Tags: php, json, mysqli

So i am writing an account login area for my game, with a json get action that is calling a log.php on my website. The json action looks like this `http://domain.com/log.php?fname='"&myUserName&"'&fpass='"&myPassword&"'`

The log.php contents are as follows.

```
<?php header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'); 

    $username = $_GET['fname'];

    $password = $_GET['fpass'];

    $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost","user","pass","db") or die("Could not connect");

    $sql = "SELECT id FROM members WHERE username = '$username' and password = '$password'";

    $result =  mysqli_query($connect, $sql);

    if($result === FALSE) { 
            die(mysql_error());
    }   

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

        echo $row['id'];

    }

mysql_close($connect);

?>
```

I get no errors from it, but it does not return the id, that is suppose to set the variable "userID" inside the game. It remains blank. Any ideas how to get this to work?

Thanks

Comment: You are mixing mysql and mysqli. Why you are sending sensitive datas with get?

Comment: There is no JSON in your example.

Answer (score 1):

change to

```html
$username = $_GET['fname'];
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use json_encode() function to generate a JSON response.

```
$username = $_GET['fname'];

    $password = $_GET['fpass'];

    $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost","user","pass","db") or die("Could not connect");

    $sql = "SELECT id FROM members WHERE username = '$username' and password = '$password'";

    $result =  mysqli_query($connect, $sql);

    if($result === FALSE) { 
            die(mysql_error());
    }   

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        $res = array("userID"=> $row['id']);
    }
    mysql_close($connect);
    echo $res_json = json_encode($res);
    ?>
```

And on you client side you will access using parsing the JSON & `data.userID`

Comment: They won't be accessing anything. Apparently they just didn't escape the inputs or something. Basically the OP wasted your time.

Answer (score -1):

Nevermind, i solved it with the help of a coding buddy. Here is the fix if you guys are interested in looking.

```
<?php 
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'); 
error_reporting(0);
require 'connection.php';

$username = $_GET["fname"];
$password = $_GET["fpass"];

$safeuser = $db->real_escape_string(md5($username));
$safepass = $db->real_escape_string(md5($password));

if($result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM `members` WHERE username='".$safeuser."' AND password='".$safepass."'")){
    if ($count = $result->num_rows){

        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
            echo $row['id'];

        }


    }
}   

  $db->close();
 ?>
```

Comment: "Nevermind" is probably the rudest way to thank the people who already spent time helping you fix something for free.

Comment: Not to mention that your "solution" that you think we're interested in doesn't actually demonstrate what significant change you made or even that you learned anything that will help you in the future. Do you think people will compare the two ambiguous blocks of your code line by line and say "oh! I see what they changed that's important!"? Because if anyone took that amount of time, I'm sure they would understand what you did wrong much better than you.  If you can't show some grace and acknowledge the help that was offered, the least you could do is delete your question.